# VsCode now is showing main.chunk.js instead on original jsx file in debugging mode

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

Before I always debug an reactjs application in vscode directly in the jsx component file. Now I can't do it because when I try to debug vscode tries to debug a file called main.chunk.js. I'm using chrome too.

[Vs Code Debugging a main.chunk.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zolTK.png)

I would like to return debugging directly in component jsx file. Do you have a suggestions of how to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here! =(

The funny thing is that the first time it works correctly by vscode, but during the debug it stops working and goes into main.chunk.js.

-------- Edit

A modification I made here and that apparently worked...

In the browser:

**Inspect > Preference Settings > Workspace > Add Folder (Project Root)**

Comment: Thanks for yours answer. I going to try. Did you read about this solution somewhere ?

Comment: I have a doubt, how I can access the path you posted "Inspect > Preference Settings > Workspace > Add Folder" ?.

Comment: @flicardie When you start debugging and Chrome instance opens right click with your mouse in Chrome and select "Inspect". Then click the cogwheel icon in the top right. It will open the settings. On the left side you will see the "Workspace" option. Click on it and on the right panel select "Add Folder"

Comment: @thatVar thank you, I tried but doesn't work for me. Any more suggestions ?. The debugger continue debugging main.chunks.js

Comment: @flicardie Do you use webpack?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @thatVar Yes, I use webpack, it Is used for the Reactjs framework

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue and tried multiple settings before reinstalling VSCode. Even installing the same version seems to have fixed this issue for me. Will update if I run into the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

Happens to me sometimes with REACT + vs code.
Usually after I save, and react live updates and recompiles the code.
I find that if I stop the npm process which is serving react: `npm start`, and then restart both it, and the vscode debugger, then everything works.

Comment: same here. I am looking for a way to fix it so I dont need to re-run npm start every time and be able to keep using hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me when working with React+VSCode. Tried some of the above with no success.
My finding are that it happens only after hot-reload.
My current solution was to stop and start app and chrome debugger, and than it works until the next hot-reload.
I'm still looking for a permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with vscode ignoring your source code breakpoints and jumping to a compiled file (such as when using TypeScript), you may have accidentally turned off **Source Mapped Stepping**.  The easiest way (for me) to check this setting, is to begin debugging with a breakpoint set.  You do not need to navigate to the breakpoint -- just have one.  Then, in the *BREAKPOINTS* section, you may or may not see the breakpoint destination as your compiled file.  Now, find the *CALL STACK* section.  The tiny button you need to click, does not appear unless your mouse is over the *CALL STACK* section heading.  It is a round and when you mouse-over the icon, it will either say "Disable Source Mapped Stepping" or "Enable Source Mapped Stepping".  Click that button a couple of times and watch the destinations in the *BREAKPOINTS* section.  You want it to show the original source code file (i.e. TypeScript file) instead of a compiled file (i.e. main.js).  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

adding

> "sourceMaps": true

to the debug config ie. launch.json fixed the issue.
[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGZB.png)