# Debugging a react app shows main.chunk.js instead of sources

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, npm, webpack

First of all, I'd like to admit that I'm relatively new to react, node, npm and etc. And I learn it when I have free time. I saw similar topic but answers there don't work.

I use Visual Studio code. I created react app using create-react-app cli command.
To start debugging I use 'npm start' command and then I start debugger in visual studio code with following launch config:

```
{
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "url": "https://localhost:3000/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", 
}
```

It works as expected - breakpoints work, VS code shows sources. But if I do any change in the sources and save it VS code starts showing main.chunk.js instead of my sources. main.chunk.js is understandable but I believe it can be fixed.
I have spent couple of weeks on this issue and you are my last hope :)

I guess after recompiling changed source file something breaks. Seems like it can't find sources or map to source file. I tried to find something that can point to sources. I found sourceMapPathOverrides property of launch config and set it to:

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "/src/*": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*"     
            }
```

But it didn't help.

I thought it might be related to src folder in the solution. I tried to change "webRoot" to "${workspaceFolder}/src" but it didn't help.
I tried to set root folder in the browser's dev tools as advised somewhere here.

Using .scripts in VS code debug console I checked loaded scripts, and it says that main.chunk.js is mapped to App.js.
When I do a change in App.js **instead of main.chunk.js it maps hot-update.js file to App.js.**
And looks like main.chunk.js isn't mapped to App.js anymore.

So how can I fix it?)

Comment: At least I'm not the only one experiencing this issue :|
Does your project deal in code-splitting in any way? Trying to find a common theme to this problem.

Comment: The following SO post looks related to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695991/vscode-now-is-showing-main-chunk-js-instead-on-original-jsx-file-in-debugging-mo

Comment: did you figure how to fix it?

Comment: @Amitk, no, I decided to try typescript+react. I created new project and slowly migrating to it. And it works as expected so far.

Comment: what about using the `outFiles` attribute of the launch config as described in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging#_mapping-the-output-location ?